# bug - <select> floating over a div that should be on top of everything

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem:

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7 with another framework - Material Design for Bootstrap by fezvrasta (http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html).
On my website, in the 3 left columns () I have a panel with some filters - filters are made with ,

Filter panel looks like this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Filter Panel -->
<div id="filterPanelDiv" class="row">
    <div id="filterPanelDiv2" class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 well">
        <p class="filterPanel_title">Filteri:</p>
        <!-- Filter - Grad -->
        <div class="form-group smallerTopMargin">
            <select class="selectpicker show-tick show-menu-arrow option form-control" data-live-search="true" title="Grad...">
                <option class="filterPanel_option">Beograd</option>
                <option class="filterPanel_option">Čačak</option>
                <option class="filterPanel_option">Ritopek</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!-- Filter - Kompanija -->
        <div class="form-group smallerTopMargin">
            <select class="selectpicker show-tick show-menu-arrow option form-control" data-live-search="true" title="Kompanija...">
                <option class="filterPanel_option">Microsoft</option>
                <option class="filterPanel_option">Nordeus</option>
                <option class="filterPanel_option">McDonald's</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!-- Clear filters button -->
        <div class="row text-center">
            <button id="clearFilters" class="btn btn-danger filterPanel_clearBtn" style="color:#2a2b35">Očisti filtere</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On my website I also have an "online support" div placed in the bottom left corner of the screen, it looks like this:

```html
<!-- Chatbox -->
<div class="chatbox" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;margin-left:1em;width:30%;">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Podrška uživo - online</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <!-- Incoming message -->
            <div class="row" style="display: flex;align-items: center;">
                <img src="img/support.png" style="width:3em;margin-left:1em;margin-right:1em;" />
                <p style="font-size: 1.3em;text-align:left;padding-left:0.8em;padding-top:0.4em;padding-bottom:0.4em;margin-right:3.5em;background-color:#e9e9e9;border-radius:0.4em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sodales vitae nisi id elementum. Sed dictum eros ex, in auctor risus pretium vitae.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Outgoing message -->
            <div class="row" style="display: flex;align-items: center;">
                <p style="font-size: 1.3em;text-align:left;padding-left:0.8em;padding-top:0.4em;padding-bottom:0.4em;margin-right:1em;margin-left:6em;background-color:#f2f2f2;border-radius:0.4em;">Ut sollicitudin libero dignissim, sodales eros sit amet, porttitor est.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Incoming message -->
            <div class="row" style="display: flex;align-items: center;">
                <img src="img/support.png" style="width:3em;margin-left:1em;margin-right:1em;" />
                <p style="font-size: 1.3em;text-align:left;padding-left:0.8em;padding-top:0.4em;padding-bottom:0.4em;margin-right:3.5em;background-color:#e9e9e9;border-radius:0.4em;">Praesent egestas vehicula dui at vestibulum. Nulla hendrerit pretium arcu hendrerit cursus.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="form-group" style="margin:0;padding:0;">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Ukucajte poruku..." style="margin:0;width:96%;margin-left:2%;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sorry I put all my CSS in style="" ...
The point is - when I load the page the "online support - chatbox" div floats over the "filter panel" but the  tags are floating over the "online support - chatbox" div:
[site when loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIxtp.png)

When I scroll down a little, it seems alright - because the "filter panel" and "chatbox" div are not overlaping anymore.

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

Filter panel is in a "container-fluid" and "online support - chatbox" is not.

Thank you in advance guys!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the **Kompanija Filter** has a `title` attribute, and the title tag shows up for some reason.

The most likely reason is that your mouse is hovering over the filter which is causing the `title` attribute to display.

You can either:

1. remove the `title` attribute which will solve your problem
2. do something like `<select class="selectpicker show-tick show-menu-arrow option form-control" data-live-search="true" title="Kompanija..." onmouseover="this.title='';">`

Comment: Solution 2. doens't work
Select titles are showing up always when these two divs are overlaping, not only when hovering with my mouse...

Comment: Then we know that it is not caused by a mouse hover.  Still, solution 1 should work.